# How to know when asynchronous forEach is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to call a callback when both `forEach` are done. I want to know when all of them are done processing `asynchronously` and call a `callback`. `console.log("Done")` seems to finish before the two `forEach`

```
const getDates =  () => {
    const ref  = db.ref("reminders");
    const dateTime = new Date();
    const currentDate = dateFormat(dateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd");

    ref
        .orderByChild('date')
        .endAt(currentDate)
        .once('value', (reminderDates) => {
             reminderDates.forEach((singleDate) => {
                 // iterate over reminder dates
                  singleDate.forEach( (notificationValues) => {
                      // iterate over notification codes
                    if (!notificationValues.key.includes('date')) {
                        processNotifications(notificationValues, () => {
                            console.log(`Sent notification reminder at ${notificationValues.key}`);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
    }).catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    console.log("Done")
};
```

Output

```
Done

AB000001_AB0977 { subtitle: 'Time to start thinking about making a payment',
  title: 'School Semester 1, 2019 School Fees',
  userId: 'kXnfHPyxfpeLQ1aCjvl8Pu09sssslou1' } d-ktpdo45SQ:APA91bF5rJtaHvtNUE42GDssssXoOAP_r7omRmsIs44WKnABsMC8lintdoDBzUYrZ5lutEKECwuaOOIQtdZkKW5Apt4A0ssssyZwdl_epdI2dYHkhk0h-Yns6jzlMbIltSHasA40YL725sssL9TmyCd
Sent notification reminder at AB000001_AB0977
```

Comment: Instead of callbacks, use promise pattern. Then, the "when all asynchronous actions are completed" problem is solved by writing `Promise.all(...`.

Comment: What is the code of the `processNotifications()` method? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: it is asynchronous

Comment: @sk123 did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> [`once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once)
>
> `once(eventType: EventType, successCallback?: function, failureCallbackOrContext?: Object | null, context?: Object | null): Promise<DataSnapshot>`

`once` returns a `Promise` which means it is asynchronous, therefore the `console.log("Done")` will be printed before your `forEach()`. You cannot know when the asynchronous operation will be finished.

Therefore, the best way to solve it is to add `console.log("Done")` inside the `forEach()`:

```
        .once('value', (reminderDates) => {
         reminderDates.forEach((singleDate) => {
             // iterate over reminder dates
              singleDate.forEach( (notificationValues) => {
                  // iterate over notification codes
                if (!notificationValues.key.includes('date')) {
                    processNotifications(notificationValues, () => {
                        console.log(`Sent notification reminder at ${notificationValues.key}`);
                       console.log("Done");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't realy use firebase but if you want to wait for multiple asynchronus operations you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

You just have to push inside an array all your async operation. Once it's finish juste write something like :

```
Promise.all(yourArrayOfPromise)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('success');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```